# Creating and closing pdf generates error when trying to exit Acrobat object

Tags: excel, vba, object, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to create an instance of a pdf document and then close it.

I added references in Tools->References.

I am getting error at the last two lines as highlighted.

```
Dim AcroApp As New Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim PartDocs() As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
.
.
.
If Not PartDocs(0) Is Nothing Then PartDocs(0).Close
Set PartDocs(0) = Nothing

'Quit Acrobat application
**AcroApp.Close
Set AcroApp = Nothing**
```

Answer (score 0):

As I still cannot comment - have you tried this approach?

```
AcroApp.Exit
Set AcroApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , I did try , It was giving the same error message.

Comment: Getting run time error " Active X Component Can't create object"